# No matching function for call to classname::constructor

Tags: c++

```
class Transport{
private:
    int weight; // Member variable (Private)
    int capacity; // Member variable (Private)
    int speed; // Member variable (Private)
public:
    Transport(int aWeight, int aCapacity, int aSpeed) { // Default constructor
        if(aWeight > 0) { // Perform validation at the time of creating object
            weight = aWeight;
        } else {
            weight = 0;
        }

        if(aCapacity > 0) { // Perform validation at the time of creating object
            capacity = aCapacity;
        } else {
            capacity = 0;
        }

        if(aSpeed > 0) { // Perform validation at the time of creating object
            speed = aSpeed;
        } else {
            speed = 0;
        }
    }
    void carryGoods(); // Member function (Public) -> Each transport has carrying goods functionality.

};

class LandTransport : public Transport{ // Inherit transport class
private:
    char * transportationMode; // Member variable (Private)
    char * vehicleType; // Member variable (Private)
public:
    LandTransport(char * aTransporationMode, char * aVehicleType) {
        transportationMode = new char[strlen(aTransporationMode)+1];
        strcpy(transportationMode, aTransporationMode);

        vehicleType = new char[strlen(aVehicleType)+1];
        strcpy(vehicleType, aVehicleType);
    }
};
```

**Can you please describe, what is wrong here and what is best practice?**

Comment: Look up "constructor initializer lists".

Comment: getting this error while creating `LandTransport ` object?

Comment: Also, while your comments are by and large trivial, you do *not* have a default constructor!

Comment: What is +1 in `vehicleType = new char[strlen(aVehicleType)+1];` And
`transportationMode = new char[strlen(aTransporationMode)+1];`?

Comment: I had [an answer](http://pastebin.com/Mt2ew3rm) you might find interesting.

Comment: vehicleType = new char[strlen(aVehicleType)+1] here +1 is for NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derived class has a constructor that doesn't provide the parameters of its parent's constructor.

```
LandTransport(char * aTransporationMode, char * aVehicleType)
```

should be like below (for example):

```
LandTransport(char * aTransporationMode, char * aVehicleType) : Transport(0,0,0)
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```